# Como importar fotos de um XML com PHP

Tags: php, xml, importação, import

Estou tentando importar um arquivo XML, mas não sei como fazer para importar quando tem um campo dentro de outro campo, veja abaixo o exemplo que explica melhor:

```
<imovel>
  <id>1</id>
  <endereco>abc</endereco>
  <fotos>
    <foto>
      <arquivo>foto1.jpg</arquivo>
    </foto>
    <foto>
      <arquivo>foto2.jpg</arquivo>
    </foto>
  </fotos>
</imovel>
<imovel>
  <id>2</id>
  <endereco>rua X</endereco>
  <fotos>
    <foto>
      <arquivo>foto5.jpg</arquivo>
    </foto>
    <foto>
      <arquivo>foto7.jpg</arquivo>
    </foto>
  </fotos>
</imovel>
```

Para os campos "comuns" primeiro nível, eu importo normalmente com o código abaixo:

```
$xml = 'arquivo.xml';
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml,NULL,true);
foreach ($xml->children() as $row) {
    $id = $row->id;
    $endereco = $row->endereco;  
}
```

Aí depois disso faço um insert no meu banco de dados.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO tabela (id,endereco) VALUES ('{$id}','{$endereco}')
```

Depois que pegar as fotos, deve ser inserida em tabelafotos, onde imd é o id do imovel:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO tabelafotos (imid,foto) VALUES {$fotoarquivos}
```

Tentei da seguinte maneira, mas não deu certo:

```
$xml = 'arquivo.xml';
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml,NULL,true);
foreach ($xml->children() as $row) {
    $id = $row->id;
    $endereco = $row->endereco;
    $fotos = $row->fotos;
    foreach ($fotos->children() as $foto) {
      $fotoarquivo = $foto->arquivo;
      $fotoarquivos.="('".$id."','".$fotoarquivo'),"; 
    }
}$fotoarquivos=substr($fotoarquivos,0,-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

> no xml falta a tag raiz.

```
<raiz>
  <imovel>
    <id>1</id>
     .....
     .....
  </imovel>
  <imovel>
    <id>1</id>
     .....
     .....
  </imovel>
</raiz>
```

> sintaxe errada `$fotoarquivos.="('".$id."','".$fotoarquivo'),";`

**Exemplo 1**

> Você precisa inserir todos os níveis da estrutura, veja

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("arquivo.xml");

foreach ($xml as $imovel):
    $id = $imovel->id;
    foreach($imovel->fotos as $items):
            foreach($items->foto as $foto):
                 $fotoarquivos.="('".$id."','".trim($foto->arquivo)."'),";
            endforeach;
        endforeach;
endforeach;

$fotoarquivos=substr($fotoarquivos,0,-1);

echo $fotoarquivos;
```

**Exemplo 2**

> Um loop foreach em torno dos elementos raiz e, em seguida, uma consulta XPath para facilitar o acesso aos elementos internos.
>
> Ainda é bastante hacky com dois loops foreach, mas funciona bem.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("arquivo.xml");

foreach ($xml as $imovel) {
    $id =  $imovel->id;
    $arquivos = $imovel->xpath("fotos/foto/arquivo");
    foreach ($arquivos as $ar) {
        $fotoarquivos.="('".$id."','".$ar."'),";
    }
}

$fotoarquivos=substr($fotoarquivos,0,-1);

echo $fotoarquivos;
```